# How do I add a transition to to text in the image caption

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a `transition:1s;` and transition the text to `color:#0000`. The text in question is 'Joe Doe' in my image caption under my image. I tried putting in several places in my css, but nothing worked. I am using a Genesis Framwork with a tru Chiliad Theme on my Wordpress site http://boasish.com/ios-8/

```
<p class="wp-caption-text">Image: 
   <a href="http://mashable.com/2014/09/25/disney-characters-halloween-costumes/" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'outbound-article', 
   'http://mashable.com/2014/09/25/disney-characters-halloween-costumes/', 'Joe Doe');" target="_blank">Joe Doe
   </a>
</p>
```

This is what I tried among several other things:

```
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #8B8080;
}

a:hover {
transition: 1s;
color: #0000 
}
```

Comment: I think you mean either #000 or #000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #8B8080;
 transition:color 1s;
}
a:hover {
color: #000000; 
}
```

```html
<a href="http://mashable.com/2014/09/25/disney-characters-halloween-costumes/" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'outbound-article', 
   'http://mashable.com/2014/09/25/disney-characters-halloween-costumes/', 'Joe Doe');" target="_blank">Joe Doe
   </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `:hover` color hex code is invalid. It should be either with 3 or 6 digits.

[**MDN Color docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Color) states two ways of expressing RGB hex values:

> For a larger palette, specify the red, green and blue components of the color you want by using a number sign (hash) and three hexadecimal digits in the range 0 – 9, a – f. The letters a – f represent the values 10 – 15:
>   **Example: #000**
>   
>   For the full palette, specify two hexadecimal digits for each component:
>   **Example: #000000**

```css
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #8B8080;
}

a:hover {
transition: 1s;
color: #000000 
}
```

```html
<a href="http://mashable.com/2014/09/25/disney-characters-halloween-costumes/" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'outbound-article', 
   'http://mashable.com/2014/09/25/disney-characters-halloween-costumes/', 'Joe Doe');" target="_blank">Joe Doe
   </a>
```

Comment: Ok didn't recognize that thank you but how do I get it to `transition:1s` from `color: #8B8080` to `color:#000000`

Comment: It is already (see snippet). But if you want it to fade both ways set the `transition` property to the main rule, not the `:hover` one

Comment: May the downvoter please explain what's wrong with this answer?